# customize ca1801 review unused parameters

Tags: visual-studio, parameters, code-analysis

we started using vs code analysis to improve our code base

is it possible to supress ca1801 - review unused parameters in event handlers?

we have thousands of event handlers like

```
Private Sub lsbRatings_Loaded(sender As ListBox, e As RoutedEventArgs)
```

and often times we dont utilize the passes parameters, but we dont really have a choice in the signature...

though i do want the warning to show when there's a truly unused parameter somewhere in code

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CA1801 does attempt to ignore event handlers.  However, it identifies them based on a signature that matches the standard convention for .NET event handlers, including an assumption that the `sender` argument will be of type `System.Object`.  Since your `sender` is of type `ListBox`, it is not being recognized by the rule as an event handler.

Comment: ok thanks. i guess il have to check out some more customizable tools. since CA has almost no configuration options.

Comment: FWIW, it's entirely possible to create a rule similar to CA1801 that will recognize your methods as event handlers.

Comment: really? can you point me to some documentation? i couldnt find any way to customize the rules. thanks

Comment: You can't customize this rule.  However, you could disable it and replace it by a custom rule that you write to do something similar while recognizing your event handlers.  If you're looking for information on how to write custom rules, http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/index.html is probably the single most complete resource.

Comment: it seems that its a bit over my head. meanwhile im checking out resharper which is excellent (thoug sloooooow) and maybe code maid. thanks all the same.